# WMI Call to retrieve Physical Serial Number on HDD's

Tags: wmi, hard-drive, wmi-query, wmic, serial-number

I'm trying to write a script that incorporates a retrieved Drive Serial Number for a report. So far I've just been trying to get a WMI call or really anything to even retrieve it in the first place

```
WMIC PATH CIM_PhysicalMedia
```

works on some computers but not in the WinPE environment I need it to work on. I keep getting: `Invalid XML Content.`

Every command I try, I use both `CIM_PhysicalMedia` and `Win32_PhysicalMedia` and neither work when it doesn't work.

What's funny is, the system it works on is Windows 7 Pro but it doesn't work on another PC with the same OS! Am I missing a dll or something?

Please help! Again this is supposed to work in a WinPE environment. I do not know the version but I do know that WMIC works normally.

Please help!!

PS I have experience with simple WMI calls like `wmic bios get serialnumber` and the like but I have never messed with anything this apparently complex.

Answer (score 0):

I have **not** **tested** on `Windows PE` environment. Give it a try. Let me know if it works or not. Run below mentioned using powershell.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select serialNumber
```